# Java-Junit / AssertionFailedError: No test in XXX

Tags: java, junit

I get the next problem:

> junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: No tests found in TestT

As I read on the Internet, this problem occurs when there is no `@Test` before the test method. So, I added it:

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Test
public void dateSimpleTest(){
    ....
}
```

but it still gives me the same error. I also import the next:

```
import junit.framework.*;
import org.junit.Test;
```

What can be the problem?

Comment: have you tried http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7995274/selenium-junit-framework-assertionfailederrorno-tests-found ?

Comment: Is dateSimpleTest the only method in this test class?

Comment: @Adam what version of JUnit are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try renaming your test method. Start the name of your test method with 'test'like 'testDateSimple'.

Comment: You should remove the Test annotation, because the test is run by the JUnit3 test runner. The Test annotation has no effect.